# No Django porque o método is_authenticated sempre retorna True?

Tags: python, django, autenticação, login

Vi que na documentação indica o método `is_authenticated` como sendo responsável por dizer aos templates se existe um usuário logado. Vi também no código do método que o mesmo contém apenas o seguinte:

```
def is_authenticated(self):
    """
    Always return True. This is a way to tell if the user has been
    authenticated in templates.
    """
    return True
```

Sendo assim não entendo como o sistema sabe se o usuário está logado. Qual o sentido desse método sempre retornar True?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Resposta rápida

Esse método aparece em models.AnonymousUser e models.User, sendo que, objetos de User só vão existir se você estiver autenticado, caso contrario você terá uma instancia de AnonymousUser com atributos default.

### Resposta Longa

O django tem uma modelagem que permite abstrair o visitante a dois niveis, usuario anonimo ou uma pessoa do sistema (user), quando você está falando de usuário anonimo é uma pessoa qualquer que está acessando, por padrão ela contem a seguinte configuração:

- id e sempre None.
- is_staff e is_superuser são sempre False.
- is_active e sempre False.
- groups e user_permissions são sempre vazio.
- is_anonymous() retorna True em vez de False
- is_authenticated() retorna False em vez de  True.
- set_password(), check_password(), save() e delete() geram exceção
- NotImplementedError.

Que é implementa pela **models.AnonymousUser**

```
class AnonymousUser(object):
    id = None
    pk = None
    username = ''
    is_staff = False
    is_active = False
    is_superuser = False
    _groups = EmptyManager(Group)
    _user_permissions = EmptyManager(Permission)
```

[Veja resto aqui ....](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py)

Caso o usuário exista(autenticado), ela se torna uma instancia de **models.User**, que por sua vez herda de AbstractUser que por sua vez herda de AbstractBaseUser onde se encontra o método is_authenticated,  AbstractUser também herda de PermissionsMixin, quem popula Users e faz a chamada a is_authenticated é **AuthenticationMiddleware** veja source no [código do github](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py)

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """
    Users within the Django authentication system are represented by this
    model.
    Username, password and email are required. Other fields are optional.
    """
    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'
```

[Veja o resto aqui ...](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py)

Olhe esse exemplo de aplicação, is_authenticated é um método de user.

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    # Instancia class models.User, existe por que está autenticado
else:
    # Instancia AnonymousUser
```

Comment: Isvaldo, no caso pelo que vi em **django.contrib.auth.models** a coisa anda assim: `AnonymousUser` herda de object e seu método `is_authenticated` **sempre** retorna `False`. Já a classe `User` herda de `AbstractUser` que por sua vez é filho de `AbstractBaseUser` cujo método `is_authenticated` **sempre** retorna `True`. A lógica seria: Se um objeto `User` foi criado, é porque ele está autenticado, por isso ele sempre retorna `True` quando o método `is_authenticated` é chamado?

Comment: Quem popula User é AuthenticationMiddleware, ela é chamada  aqui 
https://github.com/django/django/blob/b06dfad88fb12a927c86a1eb23064201c9560fb1/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py 
você está certo em sua observação, vou tentar reformular a resposta.

Comment: @JuninhoDG A ideia geral é essa, sim. Cabe notar que você pode criar/recuperar um objeto `User` via código, e esse método vai retornar `True` - ainda que nenhum usuário e senha tenham sido fornecidos. Entretanto, o `request.user` só vai ser uma instância de `User` se a autenticação tiver sido feita com sucesso (pelo middleware, como comentado, ou via chamada explícita de `login`).